# Wire Transfer Instead of Credit Card Payment

Tags: credit-card, wire-transfer

I recently wanted to buy a product from a vendor in the UK, but then noticed that they only accept cash or wire transfers for orders from the US. I'm not sure if the vendor is reputable. I was curious WHY then did not accept credit cards. To me it seems like they could be scammers.

Here is literally what they said:

> Acceptable payment methods: direct BANK TRANSFER or CASH via www.westernunion.com NO CREDIT CARDS !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's certainly reason to be careful.

Bank to bank transfers would avoid the seller's fee for credit card processing, by making you pay for the service instead. This is not a very good reason, since the seller could just adjust they price or their 'shipping fee" to absorb that.

Credit cards have some built-in protection for the buyer. (Via charge backs for failure to deliver, for example.) It's possible the seller has been the victim of having these abused and is being cautious... but they are doing so by asking you to give *them* trust they may not deserve and could abuse.

Personally, I would recommend finding another seller who isn't trying to shift these risks and responsibilities to the buyer. 
They could be legit, but at the very least this suggests you're likely to get lousy customer service.